# Java - MouseAdapter super call before or after? And why?

Tags: java, super, mouselistener

I just added a Mouseadapter to my Component in java and used mostly the autocomplete features inside VSCode.

The generated code looks like this:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mouseClicked(e);
    }
});
```

So the super call is below the Comment block. Does that mean the actual code should be put in there? Before the super call?

I thought super calls need to be done before everything else.

And also what does the super call actually do? Why is it needed?

Comment: If you have a look at the source code for `MouseAdapter` you will find that it's just a empty implementation, made to make it easier to adopt mouse listener based interfaces and not end up with hundreds of empty methods.  So, to your answer, neither, it's not needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I did take a look. I was confused about the generated code that VSCode made. So I just wanted to ask quickly. thanks.